# Not able to display the Histogram properly from a function in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I want to write a function to display a Histogram in C++ Visual Studio, The code is displaying a function to calculate histogram and display it, but I'm getting the same histogram for all the images used. The code is written below, Kindly advise where i might need improvement. Thank You.

```
class Histogram {
public:
    Mat calc_histogram(Mat src) {
        Mat hist;
        hist = Mat::zeros(256, 1, CV_32F);
        src.convertTo(src, CV_32F);
        double value{ 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
            {
                value = src.at<float>(i, j);
                //Add 1 point to the bin pixel intensity, so giving total pixels at each intensities
                hist.at<float>(value) = hist.at<float>(value) + 1;      
            }
        }
        return hist;
    }



    void plot_histogram(Mat histogram) {
        Mat histogram_image(400, 512, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));        //Image background to draw hist on &
                                                                        //Scaling it 512 pixels for clearer image
        Mat normalized_histogram;
        normalize(histogram, normalized_histogram, 0, 400, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

        for (int i{ 0 }; i < 256; i++)
        {
            rectangle(histogram_image, Point(2 * i, histogram_image.rows - normalized_histogram.at<float>(i)),
                Point(2 * (i + 1), histogram_image.rows), Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        }

        //namedWindow("Histogtram", WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow("Histogram", histogram_image);
    }
};

int main() {

    Mat img;
    img = imread("Shiv_Mahadev.png");

    Histogram H1;
    Mat hist = H1.calc_histogram(img);
    H1.plot_histogram(hist);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `=` instead of `-` here: `value - src.at<float>(i, j);`

Comment: why do you use non-static non-const member functions when you class has no state? Regular functions would be just fine for this case

Comment: yes sir, but i wanted to test it out, so i can use it in other sets as a header file, as histogram function is not available in c++ generally. Thank you.